# Why is focus-visible applied on page load

Tags: javascript, focus

If I understand correctly, focus-visible is only applied to an element if it is focused because of a keyboard interaction. However, in the following example, if I programmatically focus the element on page load, the focus ring shows up as well.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-on-page-load-jy595z?file=/src/index.js

Is this behavior expected? If so, what's the best way to disable it while keeping the page accessible (stop showing the focus ring on page load but still able to highlight the focused element with keyboard navigation)

Comment: Try to style it using `focus-within` instead of `focus-visible`. Focus visible ringis visible, because when you add the `tabindex="0"`, that is the focused element (`focus-visible` doesn't work only with keyboard events, like you mention. It works when the browser thinks the focused element need to be highlighted - like when you focus is programatically with JS)

Comment: @Boguz, I think OP wants to disable the ring until the first keyboard interaction, not force it to show.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the heuristics work this way, but I figured one can keep track of the first interaction, and style with that in mind.

```
document.body.classList.add('zero-interactions');
const clearZeroInteractions = () => {
  document.body.classList.remove('zero-interactions');
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', clearZeroInteractions);
  document.removeEventListener('mousedown', clearZeroInteractions);
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', clearZeroInteractions);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', clearZeroInteractions);
```

```
button:focus-visible  {
  outline: none;
}

body:not(.zero-interactions) button:focus-visible  {
  outline: red solid 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is expected.

**You can keep using your desired functionality and you can customize it to look as intended.** that is, hide the outline on page load and show it for subsequent focuses.

**Solution:**

- Add the following class:

  > .on-focus:focus { outline: none; }
- Apply class `on-focus` to the element you want to initially focus:

  > < span tabindex="0" class="on-focus"> focus on page load </ span>
- Using JavaScript, after the page is loaded:

  > const focus_element = document.querySelector("span");
  > focus_element.focus();

Now, on page load the desired element will focus and his outline is hidden. If you start pressing tab you will notice it begins from the span element.

What's left to do now is **remove the class** `on-focus` from the span element **as soon as it looses focus**.
You can do this by using an eventListener that runs **only once** then removes itself:

```
focus_element.addEventListener(
  "blur",
  (event) => event.target.classList.remove("on-focus"),
  { once: true }
);
```